# Constant class to String[] or List

Tags: java, constants

Background :
I'm programming an app that convert and rename files. Those files may be named like `D01234XXX123.ext` and need to be rename `FaaaabbbbbXXX123.ext`. And all have the same extension.

where :
`XXX` : the type of file (express the main content of the file).
`aaaa` : an integer for our first stage of file hierarchy.
`bbbbb` : another integer for our second stage of file hierarchy.

I've prepared a class containing the `XXX` possible values

```
public class TypeFolio {
/**
 * TypeFolio : APD
 */
public static final String APD = "APD";

/**
* TypeFolio : APP
*/
public static final String APP = "APP";
```

those are around 50 constants.
So what i wanted to do is to filter the files on the `TypeFolio` like this :

```
for(String type : TypeFolio)
(String) fileName.contains(type);
```

What are the possibilities ?
Creating the `ArrayList` on my own  ?
Or is there another way to scan all the public `String` from a class ?
Or should an `Enum` be a better option ?

Comment: I would make a Singleton TypeFolio, with a ArrayList as field and a public get and add method. Afterwards you can extend your list by calling TypeFolio.getInstance().add(YOUROBJECT). The last step would be to iterate through your Arraylist and do whatever you want with your entrys. If your types are already known go with an enum, thats the way to go for a set of constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer an enum:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "APP";
    for (TypeFolio type : TypeFolio.values()) {
        System.out.println(filename.contains(type.name()));
    }
}


private enum TypeFolio {
    APD, APP;
}
```